# DelphiMocks: Is there any way for a When clause to match every possible input?

Tags: delphi, delphi-mocks

I'm trying to setup a mock function that will return a value which is based on the input. The only way to access the input parameter that I know of is via the `WillExecute` method. However, you have to specify a `When` clause, and that `When` clause expects me to define an input value along with the method, in the following fashion:

```
aMock.Setup.WillExecute(function ...).When.myFunc(1);
```

I'm kinda forced to say: call that anonymous function, whenever `myFunc(1)` is called. I'd like to be able to do the same, but on every possible parameter to `myFunc`, with a kind of wildcard marker in the parameter to `myFunc` (conceptually):

```
aMock.Setup.WillExecute(function ...).When.myFunc(*);
```

Is something like this possible? Basically a `When` clause that will match any value passed as parameter.

Someone might be tempted to point out the `WillReturnDefault` value, but method does not have access to the actual parameters of the call, as `WillExecute` does, so I won't be able to setup anything but a constant value.

Thanks.

Comment: Now, I know nothing about Delphi, but from the description it sounds like you're trying to use a hacksaw when you really need a hammer.  I.e. wrong tool for the job at hand.

Comment: @Draco18s Last time I checked mocking frameworks were the correct tool for mocking interfaces. If you can recommend a better or more flexible alternative, I'm all ears, but before moving to any other framework, I'd like to be sure it can't be done with this one.

Comment: @kpie Do I have regex where?

Comment: As I said, I know nothing about Delphi.  Nor mocking frameworks.  I just meant that "when -> always" seems a strange way to go about it.  That is: not that you should use a different framework ("toolbox"), but that you're using the wrong method ("tool").

Comment: A mixture between the signatures of WillReturnDefault (which accepts a method name) and WillExecute (which accepts an anonymous function along with access to the call's parameters, while allowing you to return an arbitrary TValue) would be great. But before going that path I thought it would be convenient to ask others who may be more experienced with the framework. Maybe such a functionality already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I missed the fact that there was an overloaded version of WillExecute that will do exactly that:

```
//Will exedute the func when called with the specified parameters
function WillExecute(const func : TExecuteFunc) : IWhen<T>;overload;

//will always execute the func no matter what parameters are specified.
procedure WillExecute(const AMethodName : string; const func : TExecuteFunc);overload;
```

This way I can tell the mock to execute the passed anon whenever the method is called, regardless of its parameters, while still providing access to them. Exactly what I was looking for. Closing question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be solved by using parameter matching:

```
aMock.Setup.WillExecute(function ...).When.myFunc(It0.IsAny<Integer>);
```